# Custom React dropdown to be required

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

I'm using this dropdown component in my application:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import './style.scss';

const Dropdown = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  onSelect,
  options,
  selected,
  isDropdownOpen,
  extraContent,
  noOptionsContent
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(isDropdownOpen);
  const containerRef = useRef();

  const toggleOpen = () => {
    const newState = !isOpen;
    setOpen(newState);
  };

  const onOptionSelect = (option) => {
    onSelect(option);
    toggleOpen();
  };

  const outsideClick = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event?.target && containerRef.current) {
      if (!containerRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setOpen(false);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', outsideClick);
    };
  }, [outsideClick]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(isDropdownOpen);
  }, [isDropdownOpen]);

  const handleExtraContentClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  const containerOptionsClassNames = classNames({
    'c-dropdown__options-container': true,
    'c-dropdown--active': isOpen
  });

  const selectedOption = options.find((option) => option.value === selected);
  return (
    <div className="c-dropdown">
      {label && <label>{label}</label>}
      <div
        aria-labelledby="dropdown-label"
        tabIndex="0"
        className="c-dropdown__container"
        onClick={toggleOpen}
        ref={containerRef}>
        {selectedOption ? selectedOption.label : placeholder}
        <div className={containerOptionsClassNames}>
          {options.length ? (
            <div className="c-dropdown__inner-options">
              {options.map((option, index) => (
                <div
                  key={`option-${index}`}
                  tabIndex={index + 1}
                  className={`c-dropdown__option ${
                    selectedOption && selectedOption.value === option.value
                      ? 'selected'
                      : ''
                  }`}
                  onClick={() => onOptionSelect(option)}>
                  {option.image}
                  {option.label}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            noOptionsContent && (
              <div className="c-dropdown__no-options-content">
                {noOptionsContent}
              </div>
            )
          )}
          {extraContent && (
            <div
              className="c-dropdown__extra-content"
              onClick={handleExtraContentClick}>
              {extraContent}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Dropdown.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
      label: PropTypes.string,
      image: PropTypes.node
    })
  ),
  selected: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  isDropdownOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  extraContent: PropTypes.node,
  noOptionsContent: PropTypes.node,
  onDropdownToggle: PropTypes.func
};

Dropdown.defaultProps = {
  isDropdownOpen: false
};

export default Dropdown;
```

The component works fine, the problem is that I'm struggling to find a solution to make it required. For other inputs you just have to add the required attribute and it's done - a red star appears near the label and you cannot submit it without setting its value.

But in the case of this component it's more complicated.

I don't know what's the best approach, probably it is needed to send the required attribute via props:

```
const Dropdown = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  onSelect,
  options,
  selected,
  isDropdownOpen,
  extraContent,
  noOptionsContent,
  required // < --- here it is
})
```

and after that, how should the `required` attribute be used to show a red star near the label and making the field mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using custom widget, you will have to implement *all* it's functionality yourself. You will need to pass "required" prop. Then, when you collect data on submit, you will have to check that something is actually selected *if* component is required and make decisions on how to display error and prevent form from sending.